# How to resolve a git merge conflict how can I just accept all incoming?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I have a merge conflict with 90+ conflicts and I just want to accept all incoming. How can I do that? Form what I see most people just recommend using a merge tool, but what I have here has me do it one by one which at this point is unsustainable. How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: are you looking for `git merge --strategy-option theirs`

Comment: Do you want `-X theirs`, or do you want the equivalent of the `-s theirs` that Git doesn't support?

Answer (score 2):

You can set a [merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies). Try `git merge -X theirs BRANCH_NAME`. This strategy defaults all conflicts to the incomings

Comment: Which branch name do I use, incoming or present?
Incoming, right?